# Issue in Android whit no SOAPAction header

Tags: android, soap, header

I need some help.
i couldnt have access to my web service, whit android

i'm using KSoap2 3.0.0 and i'm working with android ice cream sandwich 4.0.3 (API 15)

when i call the service  i've get this response:

```
<faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
```

i show you my code:

```
       public void service()
{   
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

       Element[] headers = new Element[1];             
       Element element = new Element();
       element.setName("");
       element.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);        

       headers[0] = element;  


    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.dotNet = false;

    envelope.headerOut = headers;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.body
   }
```

i show the first part of wsdl code:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
 xmlns:impl="xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxx/xxxx" xmlns:intf="xxx.xxx.xxx" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="xxx:xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xx.xxxx.xx" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx">

    <wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="xxx:xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xx.xxxx.xx">
<import namespace="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx"/>
<import namespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
<complexType name="SOCultivo">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SOUser">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SOInfoPaginacion">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SOFinca">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SOItem">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SOEcotopo">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SOAerofoto">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SOInfoGeneral">...</complexType>
<complexType name="SORespuestaWS">...</complexType>
</schema>
```

*Thanks for all Help*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Element element = new Element();
       element.setName("");
```

Above two lines in your above code, will create an empty element like,

```
<></>
```

Now you are assigning this empty element to header.

```
headers[0] = element;
```

Now when u will call

```
envelope.headerOut = headers;
```

It will replace your soap header with this empty element.

if you want to send empty header then you could make it as below,

```
   Element [] headers = new Element[1];
   headers[0]=new Element();
```

Thats it, now on calling

```
envelope.headerOut = headers;
```

it will create empty soap header like,

```
<soap:header></soap:header>
```

If you want to add few nodes within this header, let me know your header format, i can provide you code for that.